# MySQL: Android real device not able to connect mysly in PC. Emmulator is able to connect

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to write data on MySQL which is on my laplop.
Below code works on Emulator but code does not work on real device. 
I have Wifi and I have connected android device through USP for testing purpose.
Please help.

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{
    String reg_url = "http://192.168.0.101/kiranapp/register.php";
    String method = params[0];
    if(method.equals("register"))
    {
        String name = params[1];
        String username = params[2];
        String userpass = params[3];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS,"UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("user","UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
             URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(username,"UTF-8")+"&"+
             URLEncoder.encode("user_pass","UTF-8") +"="+URLEncoder.encode(userpass,"UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            OS.close();

           InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
           IS.close();

            return "Registeration Successfull.........";

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    return null;
}
```

Error message is 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.0.101/kiranapp/register.php
on line

InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

Comment: have you added internet permissions in your manifest file.

Comment: copy http://192.168.0.101/kiranapp/register.php  and paste it in browser and check whether its working or not

Comment: Have you connect your device and pc with same network? Maybe it is silly question.

Comment: manifest contains are : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

Comment: copied 192.168.0.101/kiranapp/registerphp and I got 


( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\wamp\www\kiranapp\register.php on line 3

Comment: how to check that divice and PC are connected on same newwork. My Laptop is on wifi network and device wifi is also on.

Comment: Look into following link where there are solution for how to connect to localhost from device http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device

Comment: Followed all the instruction of :http://www.mobitechie.com/android-2/how-to-access-localhost-on-android-over-wifi/ so far no luck

Comment: 1. I have turn off the firewall
2. created a new inbound rule for port 80 
3. updated hoopd.config file as 
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
    Require local
    Allow from all 
    Allow from 192.168.0.101
</Directory>

Please tell me if I am missing anything

Comment: New error I am getting is 
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://192.168.0.101/kiranapp/register.php

Comment: some one told me to search for How to create Static API